# How can I prevent Visual Studio Code opening new windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode as what might be considered more of a "text editor" than an IDE, and I'm used to the way editors like Notepad++ work.

Is there a way to stop VSCode opening lots of windows?

I'm very much a VSCode novice at this point, but I like it for its cross-platform capability and would like to grow into its IDE functionality rather than change my workflow just to get started.

A typical example for me: I have just been editing a script on an industrial device accessed using the SSH-FS extension. That code sends data to a server which I also have access to via SSH (this time using the Microsoft remote explorer extension), and it makes more sense to be to have the files on both servers open at the same time in the same VSCode window.

Instead it seems like almost any time I open a file I'm having a new window open.

This isn't to say I don't want multiple windows open - I may well be working on several unrelated projects at the same time. I just want it to be me who decides rather than VSCode: If I open a file from an existing editor window then the file should open there. If I want a new window open I'll open one.

If this cannot be done, I'd appreciate a better understanding of *why* it can't be done.

Comment: `window.openFilesInNewWindow` setting  set to `default` (not `off`) _might_ be what you are looking for? I'm not sure though.  When you say "window" do you mean a new instance of Visual Studio Code, or simply a "tab" (editor pane) in an already open instance of Visual Studio Code?

Comment: File -> preferences -> settings -> user -> Window -> New Window -> "Open files in new window" : off

Comment: I have window.openFilesInNewWindow and window.openFoldersInNewWindow set to off but it hasn't made any difference that I have noticed.

Comment: As to what I mean by new window: Terminology may be wrong here but what I want is files to open up in tabs in the existing window, not create a new window - I should be able to Ctrl-tab between them rather than alt-tab if that is clearer. Whether it is a separate instance or separate window within the same instance is not really something I care about at this point although there may be contexts where that would matter.

Comment: does this only happen when you're using the SSH-FS extension? does it happen for regular workspaces for folders local to your filesystem?